# jQuery.Ajax with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use jQuery ajax to save the value that the user entered in the Textbox to the database. But I am struck how to proceed. What I did so far:

User clicks button and I call jQuery function and am calling the controller

```
comments = $("#txtComments").val();
var request = $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SaveCommentsData",
                type: "POST",
                data: { comment: comments },
                dataType: "json"
            });
```

and I am not sure how to get this comment value in the controller and send a value back to jQuery on success.

Comment: SaveCommentsData is name of the action in the controller?What MVC are you using?

Comment: what does the browser console say? is there a error?

Comment: @yechie yes itz a action . MVC4

Comment: Your could have sent request just like 'comments='+comments just as a plain string too.Does your browser console shows data goin to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try data like this

data :{'comment':comments}

and use the same variable as string type in controller action

```
comments = $("#txtComments").val();
var request = $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SaveCommentsData",
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'comment': comments },
                dataType: "json"
            });
```

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult SaveCommentsData( string comment)
        {

//
}
```

Regards

Comment: what if i want to send multiple texts in data: { comment: comments } ?

Answer (score 6):

script

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Home/SaveCommentsData",
   type: "POST",
   data: { comment: comments },
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {  
       // data is returning value from controller
       // use this value any where like following
       $("#div_comment").html(data);
   }
});
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveCommentsData(string comment)
{
    // save comment
    var result = someData; // maybe saved comment
    return Json(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**client side script-jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Home/SaveCommentsData",
   type: "post",
   data: { comment: comments },
   dataType: "application/json",
   success: function (data) {  
       if(data.Success)
       {
          alert('Done');
       }
   }
});
```

**controller side code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveCommentsData(string comment)
{
    // save comment
    return Json(new {Success:true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i tried and working fine. But success funciton alert not working ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
comments = $("#txtComments").val();
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveCommentsData","Home")',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringyfy({ 'comment': comments }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      alert(data.status);
    }
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveCommentsData(string comment)
{
   //Do something
   return Json(new
            {
                status = false
            });
}
```