# How can I POST data to api controller by ajax in mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to POST a string data to api controller in mvc by ajax  , but its does not go to api controller!
this is what i tried

this is my js code:

```
        jQuery(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(".listing-listing").html("");

        const jsonData = { PageNom: 1, ShowInPage: 25 };
        var data =JSON.stringify(jsonData);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Api/apiListProduct/AjaxSearchAsync',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'jsonResult',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Data.Succeed) {
                    result.Data.ProductLst.foreach((product) => AddProduct(product));
                    //$('.PaginationCell').html(result.Data.Pagination);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
            }
        });
    })
})
```

`and this is my api controller`

```
  public class apiListProduct : ApiController {
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult> AjaxSearchAsync()
    {
        string raw = "";
        using (var contentStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            contentStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(contentStream))
            {
                raw = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
}
```

thanks for helping for web api route for this api controller too.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063011/jquery-ajax-with-mvc, if so let's close it.

Comment: Which version you are using? You should pass your ajax request by parsing into json and within the controller, you should have the `FormBody` along with the class or parameters. But from the request body if you want to extact your parameters, then you should use request body in memory stream.

Comment: I did but not working.thank you Md Farid
help me for api controller route if you can
@MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: there is no need to have input for api controller actionresult!
im posting data by ajax
thanks @AlexNolasco

Answer (score 0):

> I want to POST a string data to api controller in mvc by ajax , but
> its does not go to api controller! this is what i tried. How can I
> POST data to api controller by ajax in mvc?

Well, according to your description, scenario and shared code it would be more convenient if you could share your full API controller code, which version you are using of asp.net core.

However, based on your code snippet, I initially founded two issues.

First of all, not sure hows your API route been defined so yeah, that crucial here.

Another issue is , `Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` where perhaps you were trying to read the request body. Instead, you should read request body content by using [HttpContext.Request.Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/use-http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#read-request-body). Because this gets or sets the request body Stream.

How to resolve:

In order to fix your issue, I have tried in following way and its working accordingly.

Let's have  a look in practice, how we could submit your ajax request to API controller:

API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiListProductController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AjaxSearchAsync")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AjaxSearchAsync()
    {
        string raw = "";
        using (var contentStream = HttpContext.Request.Body)
        {
            using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(contentStream))
            {
                raw = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
        return Ok(raw);
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can get rid of route annotation `[Route("AjaxSearchAsync")]` above the controller action if your API project is seperate from your MVC project. But if the API controller and MVC controllers are within the same project then you should use [explicite route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-route-constraints). Please read [route details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-route-constraints).

Request Payload:

[image]

Reuqest Body:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Alternative Approach:

Alternatively, you can use strongly type model for gettting your request parameters posted from ajax request. You can use following model.

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public int PageNom { get; set; }
    public int ShowInPage { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AjaxSearchAsyncAproachTwo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AjaxSearchAsyncAproachTwo(SearchModel searchModel)
{

    return Ok(searchModel);
}
```

Reqeust Payload:

[image]

Request Body:

[image]

**Note:** Based on my test, I found your javascript/Jquery code correct. So for reading the request body or request paramter you can follow either of above ways. In addition, please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/use-http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#read-request-body).